Error Unable to obtain connection from database for user postgres
I'm trying to test ci-cd for database ( Postgres, flyway ) from docker-compose file. I create falyway-migrate.yml and it fails due to connections:
ERROR: Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://172.31.0.2:5432/a_site_to_order_stuff?sslmode=require) for user 'postgres': The connection attempt failed.

my docker-compose file:
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:15.4-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=a_site_to_order_stuff_local
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"

  flyway:
    container_name: flyway
    image: "flyway/flyway:9.22-alpine"
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/a_site_to_order_stuff_local -user=postgres -password=postgres -connectRetries=60 migrate
    volumes:
      - ./sql/:/flyway/sql
    depends_on:
      - db


my falyway-migrate.yml
name: "Flyway CI"

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - "sql/**"
      - ".github/workflows/*flyway*.yml"

jobs:
  flyway-migrate-dev:
    name: Flyway Migrate Dev
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Flyway migrate dev
        run: >
          docker run -v $(pwd)/sql/:/flyway/sql flyway/flyway:9.22-alpine
          -url=jdbc:postgresql://172.31.0.2:5432/a_site_to_order_stuff?sslmode=require
          -user=postgres
          -password=postgres
          -connectRetries=1
          -validateMigrationNaming=true
          migrate
        env:
          ENV: dev

  flyway-migrate-prod:
    name: Flyway Migrate Prod
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: flyway-migrate-dev
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
      - name: Flyway migrate prod
        run: >
          docker run -v $(pwd)/sql/:/flyway/sql flyway/flyway:9.22-alpine
          -url=jdbc:postgresql://172.31.0.2:5432/a_site_to_order_stuff?sslmode=require
          -user=postgres
          -password=postgres
          -connectRetries=1
          -validateMigrationNaming=true
          migrate
        env:
          ENV: prod

I tried to connect to my DB by:
it's name url=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/a_site_to_order_stuff_local
By it's host:
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name
my_container_ip
The end goal is to test postgres ci-cd and also for ms sql server 2019

I see in docker logs how flyway connects to postgresby line:
Database: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/a_site_to_order_stuff_local (PostgreSQL 15.4)
but it fails in workflow:
ERROR: Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/a_site_to_order_stuff?sslmode=require) for user 'postgres':

I don't see you actually creating the postgres container anywhere in the workflow. Where is it (supposed to be) running?

Do I need to add container creation ( my docker-compose file ) to workflow?

Of course. You are currently only running the migration container, but not the database at all.

I added to my workflow file:
FLYWAY_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/test -e FLYWAY_USER=postgres -e FLYWAY_PASSWORD=postgres flyway migrate
Everything work file. Thanks to Teemu Risikko to point it out.
